# UPS RJ11 cabling

Tags: ups

I'm connecting extra battery Evolution S EXB 2500/3000 with UPS Evolution S 3000 but I do not know what type of cable to use. Typical RJ11 cable does not work (extra capacity is not recalculated, still the same). It has to be rollover cable or should it be 1:1 ? Thank you

Comment: [Here](http://lit.powerware.com/ll_download.asp?file=3400828400_AC%20%28web%29.pdf)'s a nice link to a diagram showing how they're linked, should have come with the other manuals.

Answer (score 0):

The manual says to use the included data cable and make sure you have it plugged into the right connection on the EXB unit (the EBXs support daisy chaining, so there's an upstream and downstream ports).

Comment: The problem is, that we lost this cable :/ Typical 1:1 did not work.